# How could i call child xaml method from parent in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to to perform callback response in parent xaml to child xaml, and do some stuff there

Child xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="project.NavigationBar">
        <ContentView.Content>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <StackLayout 
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="End">
                        <Button
                            x:Name="NavigationBarButton" 
                            Clicked="NavigationBarButton_Clicked" 
                            Text="Gallery">
                        </Button>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
        </ContentView.Content>
    </ContentView>
```

Child xaml.cs:

```
    private void NavigationBarButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        navigationBarButton_Clicked?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }

    public void logicFunc(params)
    {
       do stuff there
    }
```

Parent xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="project.main"
             xmlns:views="project.NavigationBar"
            >
        <views:NavigationBar
            navigationBarButton_Clicked="NavigationBarButton_Clicked">
        </views:NavigationBar>
</ContentPage>
```

Parent xaml.cs:

```
    private void NavigationBarButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationBar navbar = new NavigationBar();
        navbar.logicFunc(params); 
    }
```

How could i invoke response form parent to child xaml?

Comment: You could have a static event on the parent that the child listens out for. You could query `Application.Current.MainPage` and cast to your parent to get the instance of your parent class. You could put a property on your control view which is of type Page and set it to the parent instance on instantiation.

Comment: i'm not so strong with Xamarin.Forms XAML.
Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Are you wanting to call a method on your `NavigationBar` once you have done the appropriate logic in your **Parent**?

Comment: @TaylorD, thats correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a defined name for your child element in the parent's xaml:

```
<views:NavigationBar x:Name="NavBar"
    navigationBarButton_Clicked="NavigationBarButton_Clicked">
</views:NavigationBar>
```

then in the method being invoked by the event handler (in the parent view), you can access the element via it's name and call the public method:

```
private void NavigationBarButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    NavBar.logicFunc(params); 
}
```

Comment: well, it may work, but if i set property x:Name="NavBar",
the following error occurs:

`he type 'views:NavigationBar' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built`

Comment: If your child is in a different (sub) namespace than your parent, make sure that you are including the namespace in a using block in your parent.xaml.cs.

Also deleting bin / obj folders and rebuilding your project can resolve that issue.